# $mail->send() возвращает что то не то или ничего

Tags: javascript, php, email, phpmailer

If ($mail->send()) должен возвращает тру или нет и как следствие отправлять положительное или отрицательное $message обратно в js, но он этого не делает. Отправляю с с хостинга timeweb. Если $mail->send() удалить, и просто отправить message в js то все норм

Comment: А что у вас за объект в $mail ? Какую-то библиотеку ведь используете?)

Answer (score 0):

Все в порядке просто нужно отключать дебаггинг